# Error: "package 'genomatic' does not have a namespace and should be reinstalled

Tags: r

I have just enough experience with R to get some things done, but not enough to actually troubleshoot a problem like this. I also would not call myself a programmer, though at some point that would be great. In case it matters, I usually use Rstudio.

I am trying to solve a problem where I have different entries for the same sample (microsatellites with different runs) that I need to condense into one line of information for each sample. I found the perfect package to solve my problem (package = genomatic). The trouble is, that I could not install it for use with the most recent version of R because it was created before version 3.0. So I downloaded version 2.15.3 and am working with the regular bare bones console.

Genomatic was not available through the install packages list, so I downloaded a zip file for Windows from here: http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/genomatic/index.html

and then followed the directions from pages 6-7 in the manual (link below) to install it from my own machine.
http://people.oregonstate.edu/~knausb/software/Genomatic_users_manual_v05.pdf

It appeared to install just fine, however when I go to load the library, I get the following error:

```
> library(genomatic)
Loading required package: tcltk
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
Error in library(genomatic) : 
  package ‘genomatic’ does not have a NAMESPACE and should be re-installed
```

I looked through the forum, but could not find an answer for how to fix this. Here is the session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base
```

Can somebody help me to make this work?

Thanks!
Liz

EDIT to add: I did try to reinstall, but ended up with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting this particular error, as the .zip file provided *does* appear to have a `NAMESPACE` file.  Installing from source (which shouldn't require any extra installed tools, since the package has only R code, not any compiled [C++/C/FORTRAN] components) seems to help.  You can either do this from the official CRAN archives:

```
library("devtools")
install_version("genomatic",version="0.0.7")
```

or from the old/frozen repository:

```
install.packages("genomatic", 
   repos="http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/", type="source")
```

(My previous answer was wrong; there *is* a `NAMESPACE` file.)

Comment: Using `install.packages("genomatic", repos="http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/", type="source")` worked under linux, R ver 3.3. So it might work under Windows

Comment: Thanks Ben and csgillespie! The install code that you provided, csgillespie, worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: Ben, funny you should have that posted when I came to check back in, because I figured out how to at least unzip the tar file, and did a check and found this, and was going to ask what to do next, haha. Thanks!
    > untar("genomatic_0.0-7.tar.gz")
    > list.files("genomatic")
     [1] "DESCRIPTION" "doc"         "extdata"     "help"        "html"        "images"      "INDEX"       "inst"       
     [9] "man"         "MD5"         "Meta"        "NAMESPACE"   "R"
In any case, it is great to learn how to do new things, thanks. :-)

Comment: Ben, your 2nd bit of code worked to get the package installed in the most recent version of R, which means I can hopefully use it in R Studio, which I prefer, thanks! Either way, I should be able to get it working and solving my data wrangling problem - many thanks to both of you!